# Google Forms: Autofill fields based on data from external database

Tags: jdbc, google-apps-script

Basically what I'm trying to do is create a form with fields that are autofilled (such as name, address, email etc) based on info in the first field of the form (social security number). All data is stored in an external MySQL database.

So when I manually enter a SSN in the form, I need some kind of script to run and check the database for the corresponding values associated with the SSN, and autofill these values into the corresponding fields in the form, and if the SSN is not found in the database it should let me fill out the fields manually.

Answer (score 0):

not possible with google forms which does not support running code at form fill time.
instead write a webapp with appscript or appmaker.